# How to switch off modules on homepage with smartsearch in Joomla 3.4

Tags: php, search, joomla

I am currently building a joomla site (version 3.4) and I have an issue when I search for something on the site.
Currently the search results are shown right at the bottom of the page under all the modules that I have for my homepage.

What I was looking to find out is how I could switch off some modules so that the search results could be displayed a lot higher than they currently are.

Would appreciate some advice on how to do this as not something I have done before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not a dedicated menu item for search (no matter it's hidden or visible), the search result will be shown at the home page with a query string after index.php. To get rid of the home page content from the search result, you can simply create a menu item for search component. So, the result will be shown at that page further. This way you can also manage which modules must be show up or hide at that page.